# My MacOS Sierra won’t load up stuck at boot

Tags: macos, startup

Yesterday night while working my MacBook got stuck since it was too late instead of waiting for it to restore to normal I forced shutdown today morning I got up and MacBook with Mac OS Sierra installed is not loading and gets stuck at screen below, I managed to boot to repair mode using OPTION + Command + P + R , and repaired disk then I even tried reinstalling whole Mac OS Sierra nothing has helped so far. Please help

[image]

I think when booting normally keyboard and touchpad doesn’t respond as cursor is appearing but when touch move finger on touchpad cursor stays there. Caps lock led on button doesn’t turn on when I press it.

However keyboard and touchpad works in safe mode

Comment: I had similar problems months ago. I resetted the PRAM, reinstalled macOS and nothing helped. I even took it apart to check if any components had burned out or something, but nothing was found. And then, day later everything was back to normal as nothing had happen. I will never understand it.

Comment: I am trying to install Mac OS Sierra for the second time now let’s see, the 5 minute ETA it shows while installing is a lie , takes half an Hour at 8Mbps(can say from previous install attempt) .